# Extract element from one XML file and stuff it to another XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, copy

Is there a way within a single XSLT file to first open one XML file and extract an element with children and then stuff that element into a second XML file?

If it can't be done in one XSLT, then my choice of languages would be vb script.

I have seen many different examples here, but I am just confused and don't understand the majority of them.

Here is the XSL i have working for extracting a node from XML1:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output 
      method="xml"
      omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
      indent="yes"
      encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="root/Collection/Item/." />
    </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to take the resulting Item and append it to XML2 in the same XPATH, root/Collection.

I have a vb script from this answer [How to save XML to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628361/how-to-save-xml-to-a-file) (Thank you Andrew Cooper) that returns the XML to a memvar.

XML1:

```
<root>
 <collection1>
  <item attr1, attr2...>  ---this is what I am getting
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection1>
 <collection2>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection2>
 ...
 <collection_n>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection_n>
</root>
```

XML2:

```
<root>
 <collection1>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
---- i want to insert node from XML1 here, only in collection1
 <collection1>
 <collection2>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection2>
 ...
 <collection_n>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection_n>
</root>
```

so the new XML2:

```
<root>
 <collection1>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection1>
 <collection2>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection2>
 ...
 <collection_n>
  <item attr1, attr2...>
   <more>
   </more>
  </item>
 <collection_n>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `document()` function to load external documents so you can merge them with the one you're running the transformation on. Alternatively you can supply them as node-set to a template parameter (`xsl:param`) if you have them as DOM trees in memory when you're calling the XSLT.

Look at [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477524/how-to-concatenate-two-or-more-xml-files-using-xslt-and-maintain-the-order) that I've answered about a week ago. It's exactly about how to merge content located at the same merging point (think same XPath) from multiple documents.

Hope it helps. If it does not, please ask a more specific question about what is not clear, what have you attempted, and what isn't working for you

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't see that one.  There are many of these questions but not all of them are easy to find.  Thanks again.